# CiviEvent registration & IATS payment processing fails to blank page

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, registration, iats

IATS plugin 1.5.3 in Civi 4.7.11 on Joomla 3.6.2

First off, CiviContribute works like a charm.

Second, in backend (test) and frontend (live), CiviEvent form comes up and goes to second step correctly. Upon submitting for payment times out with this error but the payment is processed as per IATS TEST88 portal:

On Chrome:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> The webpage at
>   https://alcoholjustice.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/register
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address.
>
> ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

On Firefox:

> **Request Timeout**
>
> This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server.
>   If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this
>   web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

I'm not getting any log reports even with debugging on. I increased the PHP input and execution time limits to 5 minutes. It times out at 2 minutes.

Also, just want to be sure this is the correct URL for iATS:
https://www.iatspayments.com/netgate/ProcessLinkv2.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 1):

1.5.3 (see info.xml) file is a release for CiviCRM 4.4 - 4.6

If you're on 4.7 - you can try our pre-release master branch - I just checked and Event registrations are processing fine w/ iATS

Though what you're seeing may actually be a server configuration issue... or a issue w/ your specific CiviCRM instance;

Comment: For some reason when I disable the extension it crashes Civi. I then have to reinstall the codebase, log out, delete browser cache (b/c I think so) and log back in with a new session in order to restore Civi.

Comment: With patched extension finally installed and working from master branch the page still timeouts for event registration and never finishes the process even though the payment gets processed perfectly at iATS.

Also, for some reason when I disable the extension it crashes Civi. I then have to reinstall the codebase, log out, delete browser cache (b/c I think so) and log back in with a new session in order to restore Civi. Can I just remove all the old extension folders in custom_ext and just have 1.5.3patched there alone?

Comment: You should never manually rm -r extensions - that will cause issues - everytime you disable an extension it will trigger CiviCRM to do all sorts of other things re: ManagedEntities - it is quite possible that another extension is missing/throws a fatal error; not being able to disable the iATS extension tells us there are some serious underlying issues in your CiviCRM instance;

Comment: You are probably right. I do have an extension for SimpleDonate form that was not initially notated as Drupal only. It is just showing an "Install" link and no other. What is the process for deleting an extension then? The documentation just says there will be an "Uninstall" link. Thx.